# 'TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method' error for integer indices

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to run a few modules by gradually increasing the size of dataset. Here is the code.

```
algo_list=['bubbleSort','quickSort','insertionSort','selectionSort','mergeSort']
datasize=[(len(dataset)//i) for i in range(4,0,-1)]
print(datasize)

def calculateRunTime(algo_list,dataset,size):
    run_time=[]
    average_runtime=[]
    for algo in algo_list:
        if algo == 'bubbleSort':
            for j in size:
                for i in range(0,5):
                    start_time=time.clock()
                    bubbleSort(dataset[:size])
                    run_time.append(round(time.clock()-start_time,5))
                    average_runtime.append((sum(run_time)/len(run_time)))
                    run_time.clear()
                    visualize_datasize(size,average_runtime)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an **index**
>   method

for `bubbleSort(datasize[:size])` line. But when I print the datasize list,I see that all values are integers but not floats.

Here is the output of the print(datasize) line:
[624, 833, 1249, 2499]

Why am I getting this error though the indices are integers. I searched a few scenarios online but they have given floats as indices and so they got the error.

Comment: Can you insert the code where you are calling `calculateRunTime`? As you are using it `size` parameter to slice, perhaps you are incorrectly passing a different type

Comment: yes, got it. It was a stupid mistake. I passed size which is a list in slicing index instead of j.

Comment: Happy to help!!